# Docker exposing ports site can't be reached

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ports, get-request

I have exposed the required ports in my dockerfiles as well mapped them in my `docker-compose.yml`.

If i create containers without a docker-compose.yml i can access everything, but if i use `docker-compose.yml` file i cannot access 2 out of 3 images via a `http-get` request.

But according to `docker port <container-name>` the ports are mapped:

**bitmovin@bitmovin-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ docker port php-container 8080:**

```
0.0.0.0:8080
```

**bitmovin@bitmovin-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ docker port php-container:**

```
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080
```

**bitmovin@bitmovin-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ docker port comp-container:**

```
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8070
```

**bitmovin@bitmovin-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ docker port phpmyadmin-container:**

```
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8090
```

I don't know why i cannot access the `phpmyadmin-container` and the `php-container` but the `comp-container` if i use a `docker-compose` file.

Did i miss something important?

**php-image:**

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

EXPOSE 8080

COPY Frontend/ /var/www/html/aw3somevideo/
COPY Frontend/ /var/www/html/

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html 
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html 

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli 
RUN php -i | grep -F .default_socket
```

**comp-image:**

```
FROM java:openjdk-8u91-jdk
EXPOSE 8070
CMD java -jar encoding-comparison-1.0.jar
ADD encoding-comparison-1.0.jar  /encoding-comparison-1.0.jar
```

**phpmyadmin-image:**

```
FROM phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
EXPOSE 8090
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
db:
    image: mysql-image
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
     - /var/lib/mysql
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Bitmovin
     - DB_NAME=aw3somevideo
     - DB_USER=Bitmovin
     - DB_PASS=Bitmovin
    container_name: mysql-container

  admin:
    image: phpmyadmin-image
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    links:
      - db
    container_name: phpmyadmin-container

  backend:
    image: comp-image
    ports:
      - "8070:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/backend
    links:
      - db
    container_name: comp-container

  php:
    image: php-image
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    container_name: php-container
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change the ports from `admin` and `php` from `"8080:8080"` and `"8090:8080"` to `"8080:80"` and `"8090:80"` respectively.